# Перенос j2me приложения на андроид

Tags: j2me, android

Здравствуйте. 
Есть старенькое приложение, написаное под j2me. 
В общем-то, само по себе приложение, лично для меня, очень даже полезно, но беда вот в чем: носить с собой старенький кирпичик только ради него - не вариант совсем.

В общем-то, разрыл его - код не обфусцирован.

Теперь сам вопрос: насколько реально, скажем, портировать это приложение под ведро? Кто с этим сталкивался? Какие могут встретиться проблемы по пути решения? Может быть, есть какие ресурсы, где об этом достаточно подробно расписано?

Comment: берешь и пишешь...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблемы, как правило, при работе с GUI, файлами и, может быть, потоками. В общем, со всем тем из Java, чего нету в Android SDK. К.О. спешит на помощь.